# asking questions with "or"

Tags: grammar, questions, sentence-meaning

How should I ask this correctly?

1. Does he buy it himself or we should also buy one for him?

Or

2. Does he buy it himself or should we also buy one for him?

Many thanks.

Comment: The second half of (1) is not in question form, so you should use (2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are using 'or' in a sentence, it is always a choiceful question. From the sentences you have provided, the second one is the answer as it is an open ended question.

Comment: This answer chooses the correct sentence, but the reasoning is incorrect.